# How to prevent auto resize image in ionic card

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on a project and i simply need make this type of navigation menu in my app main page.

[image]

But if i use png image to a card that getting auto zoom and getting ugly look. That is what i am talking about

[image]

This news icon png is 50px image. I want display this as small icon. I am not using ionic provided icon because they have very limited icon list. Therefor i used other icon. If i go with ionic icons how i can resize their icon as i want?

Here my codes

```
<ion-content padding id="myPage">
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-6>
                    <ion-card color="secondary">
                        <img src="../../assets/imgs/News_50px.png" class="" alt="" />
                        <ion-card-content text-center>NEWS</ion-card-content>
                    </ion-card>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-6>
                    <ion-card>
                        <img src="../../assets/icon/icons8-handshake-96.png" class="" alt="" />
                        <ion-card-content>
                        </ion-card-content>
                    </ion-card>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

What i can do for make my app look likes above i mentioned app look and can i resize my card height and width as i want?

Comment: simply  try to use `ion-grid` systems and  read this https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-complex-layouts-in-ionic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with your png just use css.

For example:

```
ion-card img { width: 20%; height: 20%; }
```

For this apporach the images should have the same initial width and height, otherwise you need to do it with a custom class on each image and put it the size you need.

If you want to use ionic icons you can give them another size with the font-size, e.g 1.5em. Than you can check the size of the window and resize it in css. If width > 800 px, font-size: 1.8em and so on... (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you your effort nosTa :) i understood, but if there is window size change then my png again will get ugly? because of my png is so small?

Comment: if you want to keep the size no matter what happens put it in pixels. width: 300px; height: 300px. or do a max-width 30% maybe. depends what you want to do